# What is better?: To delete all elements of tkinter canvas and redraw them, or to update elements using move?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am working with a simulation of objects (circles) that live in a 2d world (the objects move and can interect with eachother, they colide).
To view the simulation I am using the tkinter module.
All the variables that define each state of the simulation are computed using a recursive function that I have outside the tkinter implementation (that way i can run the simulation without having to waste time drawing).
My question is: What do you think would be better for drawing the simulation states into the tkinter canvas?: to delete all previous state elements and redraw all new state elements for each new state, or to find a way to be able to update the position of the elements using tkinter canvas method move for each new state.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure for tkinter/python case but in general, deleting/creating objects are more resource-intensive operations then reassigning new coordinates to redraw.

Comment: Okey, makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is better to update elements rather than create new ones. You cannot create unlimited items on a canvas, and the more items you've created (even if you later destroy them), the slower the canvas will be. While the canvas can handle a few thousand items, once you start getting into the tens of thousands you will start to have problems.

Comment: Really? if you create 100 items and later delete them all the canvas will still have the 100 items??

Comment: @DanielCasasampera: yes, really. The canvas doesn't reuse item ids after you delete the item. They are a finite resource.

Comment: I dont care that much if the ids are not reusable but the information of the item surely its forgotten right? I mean theres no way of recuperating a deleted item, right? Because then whats the differences between hiding the item and deleting it?

Comment: @DanielCasasampera: yes, the information of the information is forgotten. If you just keep creating more and more items, your program will eventually crash.